# Creating seo friendly url from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a URL friendly link from a string. Instead of `example.com/Jessica Alba`, I want `example.com/jessica-alba`. How do I get the link_to tags to link me to the seo friendly permalink?

I also need to make sure that the show method only displays the seo friendly permalink in the address bar and only accepts the seo friendly permalink.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the `to_param` method in your model.

So if you have a model called `Celebrity`, which has a `name` column you can go:

```
class Celebrity < ActiveRecord::Base

  def to_param
    self.name.downcase.gsub(' ', '-')
  end

end
```

Then:

```
  jessica_alba = Celebrity.find_by_name("Jessica Alba")
  link_to "Jessica Alba", celebrity_path(jessica_alba)
```

Comment: Rails provides a method for doing that which is `parameterize`.
So I advice you to use it and create a new field called **slug** on your model. Then add a validation on the slug and method to build it. For example : 
`before_validation :generate_slug

  def to_param
    slug
  end

  def generate_slug
    self.slug = name.parameterize
  end`

And then in yout controller you do : 
`jessica_alba = Celebrity.find_by_slug(params[:slug])`

Answer (score 33):

The best thing is to use **parameterize** method:

```
name = name.parameterize
```

[Inflector#parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize)

Comment: Yeah, this is the way to go.

Comment: Unless you want to customize the slug some how, like using underscores instead of hyphens.

Comment: User the separator for customizations, e.g. Rails convention for ids ```"Tim. Cook".parameterize('_') => "tim_cook"```

Answer (score 2):

check out the has_permalink gem I've created at http://haspermalink.org

That gem will help you solve that.

Comment: There is also friendly_id https://github.com/norman/friendly_id which I happen to like