# In url, how to show title-name instead of id in ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.1, ruby-on-rails-4.2

I am using rails 4 and ruby 2 . I have created a blog part in my rails app. I need to change the url in my show page.  My problem is , I want title in my url instead of id. I want http://www.domain.com/articles/blog_title instead of http://www.domain.com/articles/9 . How can I do this? Please share with me if any one has any idea about this.

**My codes:**

**ArticlesController:**

```
def index
    @articles = Article.all
    @articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 5).order('created_at DESC')
end

def show
  @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end

private

def article_params
  params.require(:article).permit(:title, :body)
end
```

**routes.rv**

```
resources :articles
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating seo friendly url from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559323/creating-seo-friendly-url-from-a-string)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15082336/seo-friendly-urls-in-ror

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an awesome gem for this purpose named `friendly_id`, https://github.com/norman/friendly_id

In your Article model you just need to add this,

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

There are many other options available, for that you need to check the documentation.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank for the reply. I think I need to add a migration for slug. Am I going right ?

Comment: Yes, obviously.. Just follow the link and you will get the idea

Answer (score 7):

Actually you can override `to_param` method.
You don't need to have any gem for that.

If you have slug column then just put

```
def to_param
    self.slug.parameterize
end
```

If you want to go with title then

```
def to_param
    self.title.parameterize
end
```

Remember to index the slug or the title column (whichever you use) to make searching faster.

Comment: Good answer.  You should also mention that `@article = Article.find(params[:id])` should be changed to `@article = Article.find_by(slug: params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It is also a nice answer.